# Wrapping elements in fragment tag in render map behaves differently

Tags: reactjs

I have a page where there is a list of cars, and the list can be re-ordered using `<UserNumberInputCompact/>` (a [custom MUI input component](https://mui.com/base-ui/react-number-input/)) which consists of two up and down arrows which can be used to change the order of an item in a list, and a number read out to indicate the order of the items.

There was an issue where changing the order would work moving the pressed `<UserNumberInputCompact/>`. But only the `<UserNumberInputCompact/>` that was pressed would have the value/order read out inside of it update, while all the other `<UserNumberInputCompact/>` would keep their original value...this shouldn't happen because when the order of cars inside of `formState.cars` changes, then the this should re-render and assign the updated `carIndex` to the `<UserNumberInputCompact/>` components.

The only way I was able to solve this was to wrap the entire block inside of a fragment tag `<></>`. And I don't know why.

**Cars.tsx (Reduced to fit the scope of this question):**

```
<Grid>
    {formState?.cars?.map((car: CarInfo, carIndex: number) => (
      <>
        <div key={car.id}>
          <UseNumberInputCompact
            key={`stepper-${car.id}`}
            value={carIndex}
            min={0}
            max={formState?.cars?.length ? formState.cars.length - 1 : 0}
            onChange={(newCarIndex: number) => {
              onUpdateForm({
                ...formState,
                cars: reorderArray(formState.cars ? [...formState.cars] : [], carIndex, newCarIndex) // Re-orders an array of objects
              })
            }}
          />
          <CarDetails
            key={`car-${car.id}`}
            car={car}
          />
        </div>
      </>
    ))}
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?